# Is there any method to detect window screensaver?

Tags: screensaver

I want to run a program while user doesn't use desktop.
I think a screensaver is appropriate for this and there is a method to detect a screensaver because it is window's built-in function.
Is there any method to detect window screensaver? It doesn't matter what language language.

Answer (score -2):

Windows 10, neither of those methods work. Instead, press Windows+I to open the Settings app, and then click “Personalization

Comment: My interest is how program detect screensaver.